# Commit appears in git log but branch does not exist in Github

Tags: git, github, branch, commit

I made a pretty big commit by running : `git push --set-upstream origin issue11-fix-repo-run-data`

which resulted in :
`Connection to github.com closed by remote host. KB/s                                                             Uploading LFS objects: 100% (6/6), 402 MB | 697 KB/s, done.`

Now, the commit shows up in git log as :

```
commit XXXX (HEAD -> issue11-fix-repo-run-data)
```

But when I go on GitHub the branch does not exist, nor can i find the commit back.
Furthermore, when I do git status, nothing shows up in my staging area, as everything has been pushed in that commit, but I dont know where it lies now.

Please any help, I am pretty desperate given how big the commit was.

Comment: Note that `git status` doesn't tell you if anything has been pushed or not; it only gives you information about your *local* repository.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly similar to:

- [`git-lfs/git-lfs` issue 1066](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1066)
- [`git-lfs/git-lfs` issue 4147](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/4147)

A computer/network issue affects the `git push` step, while the LFS objects are being uploaded.

Check the output of:

```
GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRANSFER_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push
```

For instance, the first issue solution was:

> So, I finally figured out what my problem was.
>
> I'm using a gaming laptop and it came with a "Killer Wireless" wifi adapter.
>
> The default settings do packet scanning to try to prioritize gaming packets over normal traffic.
> This setting was severely breaking all of my ssh/ssl connections.
> I turned it off and everything works like it should.
>
> The specific setting in the Killer Control Center is "Advanced Stream Detect"

Answer (score 0):

You are in a situation where :

- you created a commit on your local clone, and that's the commit that shows up in `git log`,
- your `git push` failed, so this commit hasn't reach the central repo on GitHub yet

---

You need to debug and fix the reason why your `git push` failed.

Can you re-run your `git push` command, and paste its complete output in your question ?